# Cannot install Ruby with rbenv 2.3.1 in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu-16.04

While installing ruby with rbenv for Ubuntu 16.04 error regarding the ruby build is shown.
I've tried completely removing the rbenv and again re-installing rbenv, but all i get the following error.

I've followed DigitalOcean's procedure for installing the rbenv as in [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-ruby-on-rails-with-rbenv-on-ubuntu-16-04#update-and-install-dependencies), and followed steps listed [here](https://github.com/rbenv/ruby-build#readme) for ruby_build. I've also installed all dependencies required for the build.

Still after times of uninstall and install of rbenv problem is the same.

```
   ~$ rbenv install 2.3.1
   Downloading ruby-2.3.1.tar.bz2...
   -> https://cache.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/2.3/ruby-2.3.1.tar.bz2
   Installing ruby-2.3.1...

   BUILD FAILED (Ubuntu 16.04 using ruby-build 20170726-2-g254728e)

   Inspect or clean up the working tree at /tmp/build.20170818162042.1074
   Results logged to /tmp/ruby-build.20170818162042.1074.log

   Last 10 log lines:
   linking shared-object objspace.so
   make[2]: Leaving directory '/tmp/ruby-build.20170818162042.1074/ruby-2.3.1/ext/objspace'
   installing default date_core libraries
   linking shared-object date_core.so
   make[2]: Leaving directory '/tmp/ruby-build.20170818162042.1074/ruby-2.3.1/ext/date'
   linking shared-object nkf.so
   make[2]: Leaving directory '/tmp/ruby-build.20170818162042.1074/ruby-2.3.1/ext/nkf'
   make[1]: Leaving directory '/tmp/ruby-build.20170818162042.1074/ruby-2.3.1'
   uncommon.mk:203: recipe for target 'build-ext' failed
   make: *** [build-ext] Error 2
```

Result of cat /tmp/ruby-build.20170818162042.1074.log

```
In file included from ossl.h:57:0,
                 from ossl_bn.c:11:
/usr/include/openssl/asn1_mac.h:10:2: error: #error "This file is obsolete; please update your software."
 #error "This file is obsolete; please update your software."
  ^
In file included from ossl.h:221:0,
                 from ossl_bn.c:11:
openssl_missing.h:78:35: error: macro "EVP_MD_CTX_create" passed 1 arguments, but takes just 0
 EVP_MD_CTX *EVP_MD_CTX_create(void);
                                   ^
In file included from /usr/include/openssl/x509.h:23:0,
                 from /usr/include/openssl/x509v3.h:14,
                 from ossl.h:58,
                 from ossl_bn.c:11:
openssl_missing.h:82:6: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘(’ token
 void EVP_MD_CTX_init(EVP_MD_CTX *ctx);
      ^
openssl_missing.h:90:6: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘(’ token
 void EVP_MD_CTX_destroy(EVP_MD_CTX *ctx);
      ^
ossl_bn.c: In function ‘ossl_bn_size’:
ossl_bn.c:43:19: error: invalid application of ‘sizeof’ to incomplete type ‘BIGNUM {aka struct bignum_st}’
     return sizeof(BIGNUM);
                   ^
ossl_bn.c: In function ‘ossl_bn_s_generate_prime’:
ossl_bn.c:769:5: warning: ‘BN_generate_prime’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
     if (!BN_generate_prime(result, num, safe, add, rem, NULL, NULL)) {
     ^
In file included from /usr/include/openssl/bn.h:31:0,
                 from /usr/include/openssl/asn1.h:24,
                 from /usr/include/openssl/objects.h:916,
                 from /usr/include/openssl/evp.h:27,
                 from /usr/include/openssl/x509.h:23,
                 from /usr/include/openssl/x509v3.h:14,
                 from ossl.h:58,
                 from ossl_bn.c:11:
/usr/include/openssl/bn.h:285:1: note: declared here
 DEPRECATEDIN_0_9_8(BIGNUM *BN_generate_prime(BIGNUM *ret, int bits, int safe,
 ^
ossl_bn.c: In function ‘ossl_bn_is_prime’:
ossl_bn.c:877:5: warning: ‘BN_is_prime’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
     switch (BN_is_prime(bn, checks, NULL, ossl_bn_ctx, NULL)) {
     ^
In file included from /usr/include/openssl/bn.h:31:0,
                 from /usr/include/openssl/asn1.h:24,
                 from /usr/include/openssl/objects.h:916,
                 from /usr/include/openssl/evp.h:27,
                 from /usr/include/openssl/x509.h:23,
                 from /usr/include/openssl/x509v3.h:14,
                 from ossl.h:58,
                 from ossl_bn.c:11:
/usr/include/openssl/bn.h:291:1: note: declared here
 DEPRECATEDIN_0_9_8(int
 ^
ossl_bn.c: In function ‘ossl_bn_is_prime_fasttest’:
ossl_bn.c:916:5: warning: ‘BN_is_prime_fasttest’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
     switch (BN_is_prime_fasttest(bn, checks, NULL, ossl_bn_ctx, NULL, do_trial_division)) {
     ^
In file included from /usr/include/openssl/bn.h:31:0,
                 from /usr/include/openssl/asn1.h:24,
                 from /usr/include/openssl/objects.h:916,
                 from /usr/include/openssl/evp.h:27,
                 from /usr/include/openssl/x509.h:23,
                 from /usr/include/openssl/x509v3.h:14,
                 from ossl.h:58,
                 from ossl_bn.c:11:
/usr/include/openssl/bn.h:295:1: note: declared here
 DEPRECATEDIN_0_9_8(int
 ^
ossl_bn.c: In function ‘ossl_bn_size’:
ossl_bn.c:44:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
 }
 ^
Makefile:301: recipe for target 'ossl_bn.o' failed
```

Comment: Can you the result of `cat /tmp/ruby-build.20170818162042.1074.log`?

Answer (score 4):

This is a known compatibility issue with openssl and ruby 2.3.x.

The openssl extension of Ruby version before 2.4 is not compatible with OpenSSL 1.1.x. At the moment, most Linux distributions that come with OpenSSL 1.1.0 have a separate package for OpenSSL 1.0.x.

You need to install the earlier version of OpenSSL or use ruby 2.4.x.

[full description and solution here](https://github.com/rbenv/ruby-build/wiki#openssl-usrincludeopensslasn1_mach102-error-error-this-file-is-obsolete-please-update-your-software)

Answer (score 2):

I was able to successfully build docker image with the following Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

ENV RBENV_ROOT=/usr/local/rbenv
ENV PATH=$RBENV_ROOT/bin:$RBENV_ROOT/shims:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    build-essential \
    cmake curl git zlib1g-dev \
    libssl-dev libreadline-dev \
    libyaml-dev libxml2-dev \
    libxslt-dev libsqlite3-dev \
    python-dev libxml2-dev \
    libxslt-dev groff zip \
    pkg-config ca-certificates \
    && apt-get clean

# Install rbenv
RUN git clone https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv.git /usr/local/rbenv \
    && echo '# rbenv setup' > /etc/profile.d/rbenv.sh \
    && echo 'export RBENV_ROOT=/usr/local/rbenv' >> /etc/profile.d/rbenv.sh \
    && echo 'export PATH="$RBENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH"' >> /etc/profile.d/rbenv.sh \
    && echo 'eval "$(rbenv init -)"' >> /etc/profile.d/rbenv.sh \
    && chmod +x /etc/profile.d/rbenv.sh

ENV RUBY_VERSION=2.3.1

# install ruby-build
RUN mkdir /usr/local/rbenv/plugins \
    && git clone https://github.com/sstephenson/ruby-build.git /usr/local/rbenv/plugins/ruby-build \
    && /usr/local/rbenv/plugins/ruby-build/install.sh \
    && rbenv install ${RUBY_VERSION} \
    && rbenv global ${RUBY_VERSION} \
    && gem install bundler \
    && rbenv rehash
```

Some tests

```
$ docker run -it --rm test rbenv version
2.3.1 (set by /usr/local/rbenv/version)

$ docker run -it --rm test ruby -v
ruby 2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26 revision 54768) [x86_64-linux]
```