# rbenv install 2.2.1 BUILD FAILED Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ruby, rbenv

Here is the error log

```
Downloading ruby-2.2.1.tar.bz2...
-> https://cache.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/2.2/ruby-2.2.1.tar.bz2
Installing ruby-2.2.1...

WARNING: ruby-2.2.1 is past its end of life and is now unsupported.
It no longer receives bug fixes or critical security updates.


BUILD FAILED (Ubuntu 16.04 using ruby-build 20181019-2-gd49b8a1)

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /tmp/ruby-build.20181025114001.11061
Results logged to /tmp/ruby-build.20181025114001.11061.log

Last 10 log lines:
make[2]: Leaving directory '/tmp/ruby-build.20181025114001.11061/ruby-2.2.1/ext/objspace'
installing default date_core libraries
installing default nkf libraries
linking shared-object nkf.so
linking shared-object date_core.so
make[2]: Leaving directory '/tmp/ruby-build.20181025114001.11061/ruby-2.2.1/ext/nkf'
make[2]: Leaving directory '/tmp/ruby-build.20181025114001.11061/ruby-2.2.1/ext/date'
make[1]: Leaving directory '/tmp/ruby-build.20181025114001.11061/ruby-2.2.1'
uncommon.mk:189: recipe for target 'build-ext' failed
make: *** [build-ext] Error 2
```

I'm not sure what to do here. I am new to rbenv. I try to fix this issues searching on google but nothing work also I've try to install `apt-get install autoconf bison build-essential libssl-dev libyaml-dev libreadline6 libreadline6-dev zlib1g zlib1g-dev`
here is the complete log [ruby-build.20181025125952.32167.log](https://pastebin.com/GZNNv46S)

Comment: Last 10 log lines are not enough to find out why. You need to check the log file or post more lines.

Comment: @halfelf hi i've edited the question please take a look again

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45755066/cannot-install-ruby-with-rbenv-2-3-1-in-ubuntu-16-04